# check if total items fit in rows of three

Tags: php

I'm displaying entries in rows of 3. If the last row only has 1 or 2 entries I want to fill up the row with 1 or 2 static items.
Example. Total entries is 8. I've got 3 rows and on the final row 1 empty spot.

Comment: Add some code to this question and we will be able to help you.

Comment: Yes. Add some code so we can help :)

Comment: Total-Current = how many you need to fill. Find how many you need to fill, then do a loop to fill that many items.

Comment: Sorry. Submitted my question to soon. Wasn't finished. 
No code yet. I couldn't figure out how to do this. But Dave Chen pointed me out in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulus operator (returns result from division):

```
if($var % 3 == 0)
{
//is divisible by 3
}
else
{
//is not divisible by 3
}
```

Comment: Actually it should be `$var % 3 == 0`

Comment: Ohhh I get it, +1 nevermind.

Comment: @zerkms oops, sorry. Thanks for your comment :)